How would a third party intercept this communication
I've only recently gotten into encrypted communication through the internet, after reading a bunch of articles about how police have been cracking the communications of international criminals.
Was thinking about how one might create a safe way of chatting with each other online that would be hard to crack, and had an idea. It probably has dozens of weaknesses, but I simply cannot come up with what these might be and would like to hear if anyone here could educate me.

When a User (Alpha) wants to contact another user (Beta) for the first time, the Server checks if Beta is currently online. If Beta is online, the Server informs Alpha about the current IP of Beta while also informing Beta to expect an incoming message from Alpha.
Alpha will generate a Key Pair and send the Public Key directly to Beta, without using the Server as a middle-man.
Beta will generate an entirely different Secret Key based on the user's local settings. When Beta receives the Public Key, it will use it to encrypt the Secret Key (along with any necessary information about it that would be required to use it) and send this encrypted information directly to Alpha (once again without the Server being involved).
Using their now shared Secret Key, Alpha and Beta would be able to send messages between each other. They could now use the Server to store/pass on these messages, as the Server would have no idea how they are encrypted.

So, how would one crack this kind of communication? Other than getting your hands on a user's phone/computer and just reading their stuff that is.

This would allow a classic man-in-the-middle attack as alpha's key is not authenticated. The Internet is an insecure channel where an adversary can observe and block messages and interject their own.
At step 2 the adversary blocks the transmission of alpha's key and injects a message of their own with a public key associated to a private key known to the adversary. They represent this as alpha's key and beta has no means to falsify this representation.
At step 3 beta sends the secret key encrypted with the adversary's public key. Again the adversary blocks the transmission. The adversary recovers the secret key using the adversarial private key and can re-encrypt the secret key using alpha's public key. They then inject a message to alpha purportedly from beta, which is the expected transmission of the secret key. Again alpha cannot determine that this message was in fact created by the adversary rather than beta.
At step 4 and thereafter, the adversary need merely observe and decrypt messages as they have knowledge of the secret key.

That definitely does sound like it'd work in theory, but I kind of wonder if anyone (powerful government agency or not) has the ability to really make that kind of thing work. The vulnerability you're proposing only exists for a moment, during first-contact, and requires an immense amount of control over the internet on at least a national level along with knowing exactly who is using the app for criminal deeds.
Do you consider your answer practical or just theoretical?

@AnjuMaaka I consider it practical based on recorded instances

Fair enough. Though it makes me wonder if secure communications online is at all possible. If a Man-in-the-middle has such control over the internet, can't they fake authentication too?
